# Web API model binder maps null value for action method parameter in .NET Framework 4.7

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, model-binding, refit, .net-4.7

Working with a legacy app that uses .NET Framework 4.7 and exposes a couple of Web API endpoints. The parameter is a `ICollection<Guid>` type.

```
[HttpPost("customer/process")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ProcessCustomers([FromBody] ICollection<Guid> customerIds, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
     // customerIds is null if the collection has more than 24 Guids
}
```

Using the refit client to make the HTTP post request.

```
public interface IRefitApiClient 
{
   [HttpPost("/api/xyz/customer/process")]
   [Headers("content-type: application/json")]
   public async Task<int> ProcessCustomers([Body] IEnumerable<Guid> customerIds, CancellationToken token);
}
```

Body:

```
[
"46dadad3-f8da-4a0e-a97d-69a21684f720",
"56da249b-70b2-4e74-998f-4101541ca492",
"3afcc23e-e1f8-4b3b-9ca1-acaf038c86c4",
"7c1321b4-4944-47f7-b248-f65c6acb246e"
.
.
.
]
```

If the collection has 24 or less GUIDS, the endpoint receives all of them. More than 24 GUIDs, the endpoint just receives null value.

I tried increasing all the request limits in the `web.config` of the Web API service but no avail. The service runs on IIS but haven't made any changes there. None of these seems to help.

```
maxJsonLength="2147483644"
maxRequestLength="2097151"
maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295"
aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers value="10000000"
```

Is this is a limitation on refit client or I have to change something on IIS? However, I can successfully post a list of like 5000 guids with postman when running the service locally on IIS express in VS. This suggests something needs to be adjusted in IIS server in production.   TIA

***Update***

I serialized the list of 200 Guids before passing them to refit, it works without any issue.

```
var foo = new List<Guid>{'guid1', 'guid2', 'guid3'.....};
var bar = JsonSerializer.Serialize(foo);
var res = _refitApiClient.ProcessCustomers(bar, cancellationToken);
```

```
public interface IRefitApiClient 
{
   [HttpPost("/api/xyz/customer/process")]
   [Headers("content-type: application/json")]
   public async Task<int> ProcessCustomers([Body] string customerIds, CancellationToken token);
}
```

I had to change the `IEnumerable<Guid>` to `string` as you can see above. This pretty hacky. So the issue is with the refit client after all. Even though I stringyfied guid collection on the client side, the api endpoint correctly deserializes it into List without the manual intervention.

I had a similar refit issue with passing DateTime to the api. I had to convert it to string like I did here.  I must be missing some refit configuration somewhere.  Surprised the models needs to be stringyfied before passing. Wasted a lot of time on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the refit client.  It stream the POST contents by default and therefore doesn't send the content-length to the api.  You want the refit client to buffer the request and send all at once.

Add the `Buffered: true` in the `Body` attribute like this:

```
public interface IRefitApiClient 
{
   [HttpPost("/api/xyz/customer/process")]
   [Headers("content-type: application/json")]
   public async Task<int> ProcessCustomers([Body(Buffered: true)] IEnumerable<Guid> customerIds, CancellationToken token);
}
```

Now the model binder won't bind the parameter to null.  Buffering should've been the default.  I wasted a lot of time on this issue!